# Does XCode iOS Simulator require internet access?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, xcode6

I am trying to build an iPhone application in Xcode 6.1, however the code was delivered from an external company.

For security reasons, the test server that the application is (supposed to be) talking to is on a separate network which does not have internet access.

When I build and run the app on the simulator with this network, there is an error thrown (on the app) almost immediately and the app doesn't run.

When I build the app using a network with internet access, the app starts successfully - but obviously can't reach the destination server.

The company are INSISTING that internet access is required to validate my iOS provisioning profile...whereas I am pretty sure its something in the app.

Is internet access REQUIRED to build and run an application on the simulator from XCode?

---

I *think* this is the error...but I'm a C#/Windows guy who knows v. little about XCode!
Pretty sure this is an error thrown by the application and not the emulator.

```
*********************************** Server Response END FAI BLO******************************
2014-11-12 14:33:04.019 FCiOS12P2[11017:60b] **** error is :Error Domain=KFCRMSErrorDomaininResourceUpdate Code=3126 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (KFCRMSErrorDomaininResourceUpdate error 3126.)"
2014-11-12 14:33:04.020 FCiOS12P2[11017:60b] Failed to get token, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator" UserInfo=0x7978acd0 {NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not supported in the simulator}
2014-11-12 14:33:09.059 FCiOS12P2[11017:60b] FCAlertView: FCAlertOverlayWindow dealloc
2014-11-12 14:33:09.060 FCiOS12P2[11017:60b] FCAlertView: FCAlertViewController dealloc
2014-11-12 14:34:29.706 FCiOS12P2[11017:60b] Reachability Flag Status: -R -----l- networkStatusForFlags
2014-11-12 14:34:29.707 FCiOS12P2[11017:60b] -[NetworkStatusManager checkNetworkStatus:] [Line 89] The internet is working via WIFI.
```

Comment: i dont think so they might have a rechability test in there app delegate can you show us the error which is thrown?

Comment: It's a simulator, not an emulator.

Comment: Maybe that one is causing the issue: `remote notifications are not supported in the simulator`. Have you tried it on an device?

Comment: Fails on device with same error...and company triewd telling me it was because of my provisioning profile...its not.  They've now admitted a bug and are re-writing as we speak...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a provisioning profile to use the iPad simulator, and you don't need internet access to use the iPad simulator.

Comment: So, it's 99.99999% that its their application itself making some kind of connection/check for internet?

Answer (score 0):

This line `Failed to get token, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator"`
Should mean that your app uses push notification but you can't get the token on the simluator.

Anyways the answer is NO, you don't need internet access to run app on the iPad simulator

Answer (score 0):

The application you are dealing with uses microsoft RD client? It has recently been updated to 8.1.0.The error you are facing in URL not recognized.This will not work on simulator.There is a bug on wifi desktop application using this client are working if connected to LAN

If its about RD 8.1.0 client you cannot solve it wait for update

debug on device .

Comment: Thanks - however more testing revealed this works on 8.1, but not on 7.1